# Is it possible to solve a linear inequality system using SVD?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, svd

I have a large linear inequality system of the form $Ax ≤ 0$.
Is there a way to solve this system using linear algebra tools like SVD?

Comment: What if matrix $A$ had a non-negative left-inverse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; loosely speaking this problem is more related to [linear programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming), which is not equal to linear algebra.

(Plugging in an SVD of $A$ will be too helpful as you probably have seen.)

The set $Ax\leq 0$ is a [convex polytope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polytope) and the representation $Ax\leq 0$ is called its H-representation because it is a description as intersection of half-spaces. Another representation is its V-representation which consists of a list of the vertices. The Wikipedia entry on convex polytopes has more pointers.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought.  
I know it can be solve using linear-programming, and indeed, my desired solution is the list of vertices. Thanks.